# Javascript title flashing method

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Ok, I know that this question is similiar to others, but I am not looking for any code, purely just a push in the right direction.

I have some code that will update a browser title based on the values of a table changing. Everytime a new value or message appears in the table I want the browser tab to flash, to notify the user. The problem I am having is that no matter what I do, only the `==` part of my `function()` if statement is being called. See my code below..

```
function newMessage() 
     {
      var oldTitle = "Web Page";
      var msg = "You have a new message";

      var timeout = setInterval(function() 
      { 
        document.title = document.title == msg ? '' : msg;
      }, 1000);

      window.onmousemove = function() {
          clearInterval(timeout);
          document.title = oldTitle;
          window.onmousemove = null;
      };
     }

    function notification()
    {

          var table = document.getElementById('refreshMessages');

          var counter = 0;
          var firstTr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr")[1];
          var firstTd = firstTr.getElementsByTagName("td")[0];

          updater.start();
          updater2.start();

          var firstTrUpdate = table.getElementsByTagName("tr")[1];
          var firstTdUpdate = firstTrUpdate.getElementsByTagName("td")[0];

          if(firstTd.innerHTML != firstTdUpdate.innerHTML)
           {
             newMessage();
           }
           else if(firstTd.innerHTML == firstTdUpdate.innerHTML)
             {
                alert(firstTd.innerHTML);
             }
    }
```

The `alert()` which I have in for testing reasons, shows the value of the cell in question, so I know that my code is accessing the cell and retrieving the data. however the `!=` part of the if statement never seems to execute. After 4 or 5 hours of looking and re-writing the same code I am at a loss! It doesn't help when you are not too familiar with JavaScript either :)

If anyone could point out my errors to me, or even give me a hint or two I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: What happens if you change it to read  as follows (added parenthesis around logic): `document.title = (document.title == msg) ? '' : msg;`

Comment: Do you actually want to compare innerHTML or the text value of that table cell? Perhaps you actually want the textContent property? (http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-DOM-Level-3-Core-20040407/core.html#Node3-textContent) I'd suggest trimming it to remove any whitespace as well.

Comment: What do you mean, _"the `==` part?"_ The code has `==` more than once, so this is ambiguous and unclear.

Comment: Is the first cell of the second row only cell which will have new content using `start()`-methods (or any way)? If changes are made somewhere else in the table, they are not checked.

Comment: I have made these changes, but they seem to have no affect and I am still having the same problem. I have stepped through everything with Firebug and everything seems to check out there.

Answer (score 0):

why dont you organize like this?

```
if(firstTd.innerHTML == firstTdUpdate.innerHTML){
  alert(firstTd.innerHTML);
}else{
 newMessage();
}
```

Comment: I ordered it like this, but I still have the same problem. It won't recognise the table change.